# Contact form - leaving the form and resuming it later

Tags: views, 7, forms, emails

Is it possible to have a contact form in drupal, which you can save, and resume later?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can build a contact form with the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module and use its "Save Draft" feature.